# Split date string into variables

Tags: jquery, parsing, datetime

I have the following date -

```
201409290000
```

I am trying to split this using the following -

```
var timePeriodDay = timePeriod.substring(6, Math.min(timePeriod.length, 2));
var timePeriodMonth = timePeriod.substring(4, Math.min(timePeriod.length, 2));
var timePeriodYear = timePeriod.substring(0, Math.min(timePeriod.length, 4));
var timePeriodTime = timePeriod.substring(8, Math.min(timePeriod.length, 4));
var timePeriodTime = [timePeriodTime.slice(0, 2), ":", timePeriodTime.slice(2)].join('');
```

However my logic seems to be off, where the desired output should be -

```
var timePeriodDay = 29
var timePeriodMonth = 09
var timePeriodYear = 2014
var timePeriodTime = 00:00
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's `substring(to, from)`, so for the day it should be simply `timePeriod.substring(6, 8);` not whatever you're trying to do ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q1c5b389/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`.substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) instead of [`.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) since your second arg is number of char to extract.

```js
var timePeriod = '201409290000';
var timePeriodDay = timePeriod.substr(6, Math.min(timePeriod.length, 2));
var timePeriodMonth = timePeriod.substr(4, Math.min(timePeriod.length, 2));
var timePeriodYear = timePeriod.substr(0, Math.min(timePeriod.length, 4));
var timePeriodTime = timePeriod.substr(8, Math.min(timePeriod.length, 4));
var timePeriodTime = [timePeriodTime.slice(0, 2), ":", timePeriodTime.slice(2)].join('');
alert(timePeriodDay + ' ' + timePeriodMonth + ' ' + timePeriodYear + ' ' + timePeriodTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
timePerio = '201409290000';


var timePeriodYear = timePerio.substr(0,4);
var timePeriodMonth =timePerio.substr(4,2);
var timePeriodDay = timePerio.substr(6,2);
var timePeriodTime = timePerio.substr(8,2)+':'+timePerio.substr(10,2);
```